# Адаптивная верстка и bootstrap

Tags: html, css, bootstrap

Имеется страница с использованием сетки bootstrap. На странице два элемента col-*, первое с контентом, второе с меню.

```
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-9 col-12 content">
Контент
</div>
<div class="col-md-3 col-12 menu">
Меню
</div>
</div>
```

При просмотре с малых экранов верстка соответственно съезжает, контент сверху, а меню ниже. Мне необходимо, чтобы меню было сверху. Как это можно реализовать?

Comment: Привет! Добавьте [минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: ну так вы сами дословно в коде написали: при разрешении md и меньше (720px) делать разметку вертикальной. класс col-xx-n при разрешении > xx расширяется до n, а при меньшем перестает работать и начинает работать col-12.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Визуальное изменение порядка](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.2/utilities/flex/#order) работает для flex элементов. Дополнительно, посмотрите [эту информацию](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/CSS/order)

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.0-beta1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-0evHe/X+R7YkIZDRvuzKMRqM+OrBnVFBL6DOitfPri4tjfHxaWutUpFmBp4vmVor" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-9 col-12 order-1 content">
    Контент
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-3 col-12 order-md-1 menu">
    Меню
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Большое Вам спасибо.